# Vertical spacing around UL tag

Tags: html, tags, format, html-lists

One of the unintended differences between a `<div>` tag and a `<ol>` or `<ul>` tag is that the list tags add 20px of padding at the top and bottom of the block to whatever is specified in the style properties.

In fact, using a `<div><li></li><li></li></div>` gives exactly the desired results.  Although this workaround is apparently illegal- (question [2031725](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031725/is-using-li-without-enclosing-ul-tags-dangerous)).  I'm guessing this workaround is what the poster had in mind.

Firefox/Safari/IE share this behavior.  Does this problem originate in the HTML specification?  Is there another obvious work-around?  This seems like an obvious flaw and I hear lots of complaints.

Comment: You can't have list items without a list. It is what's first, egg or a chicken type of thing. Use standard HTML and CSS to achieve desired result. Also this is not a work around, it's just ill formatted HTML.

Comment: HTML is for marking up what some text *is* (a list, paragraph, table etc.), CSS is for controlling how it looks. Try and stick with that mindset and you'll live longer.

Answer (score 4):

The vertical space around `<ol>` and `<ul>` tags is not part of HTML, but of browsers' default styling.  If you don't like the style, [change it](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties) rather than using invalid HTML.

I'd also argue against "unintended differences".  `<ol>` and `<ul>` have inherent, semantic meaning (that of ordered and unordered lists, respectively) and so browsers by default style them to support that meaning.  `<div>` has (almost) no semantic meaning at all, so is unstyled by default.