# Jquery Toggle Independently

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div with multiple lis and each li contains ul. I want to independently toggle each li. like if I click on a link it should only toggle the ul of that group, Hope the below code will clear things more than my words.

```
<div id="sortable" style='width:700px; margin: 0 auto; border:2px solid; border-color:grey;'>
 <li class="ui-state-default"><a href='#' id='expand'> Group 1</a>
    <ul style= 'display:none' class='patents' id="sortable">
        <li id ='1' class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li id ='2' class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li id ='3' class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="ui-state-default"><a href='#' id='expand'> Group 2</a>
    <ul style= 'display:none' class='patents' id="sortable">
        <li id ='4' class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li id ='5' class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
        <li id ='6' class="ui-state-default">Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The script is

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#expand').click(function() {
        $('.patents').toggle('slow', function() {
                    //instead of patents i need something unique 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

If I click on group 1 the item 1,2,3 should toggle , if I click on group2 then Item 4,5,6 should toggle how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: @Siva Charan whay? wat is wrong?

Comment: Hint: Id must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put class="expand" instead of id="expand" on the top-level

(you shouldnt have repeated ids anyway).

Then use a class selector "." instead of id "#" and select only ".patents" which are children of the element clicked

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.expand').click(function() {
         $(this).next().toggle('slow', function() {
                    //instead of patents i need something unique
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I did wat u suggested but now nothing becomes visible

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your call to $('.patents') gets everything on the page with that class. Instead, you need to start from the clicked element. Inside of a click function, $(this) references the current element. You can then use the find method to locate a decendent of the clicked element.

Replace $('.patents') with $(this).find('.patents'), and you should be good to go.

Also, a couple of minor housekeeping items:

1. Instead of id='expand', you should probably use class='expand', and change your script to reference '.expand' instead of '#expand'
2. You shouldn't be using the top level li tags without am enclosing ul tag. See [Is using <li> without enclosing <ul> tags dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031725/is-using-li-without-enclosing-ul-tags-dangerous).

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/zeS8u/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="clickme">Click me!</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Cat</li>
            <li>Dog</li>
            <li>Mouse</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="clickme">Click me too!</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Zebra</li>
            <li>Lion</li>
            <li>Snow Yeti</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Javascript:

```
$("a.clickme").bind("click", function(e) {
   $(this).next("ul").toggle(); 
    return false;
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

id attribute is unique so you need to change to class:

For example:

```
<li class="ui-state-default"><a href='#' class='expand'> Group 2</a>
```

Then do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.expand').each(function(){
    ($this).click(function() {
      var patents = $(this).next();
      $(patents).toggle(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      },
      function(){
        $(this).show();
      });
  });
});
```