# internet explorer 7 place a not existing <UL> in a Magento Form

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-lists, internet-explorer-7

All browsers are respecting my code except the IE7 that put a `</ul>` that does not exist in my code, finishing with my form structure.

The code below is generated in the source code of IE9:

```
<div class="fieldBairro_end">
                    <li class="fields">
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="bairro_end" id="complemento_end" class="required"><em>*</em>Bairro</label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="text" name="bairro_end" value="" title="bairro_end" id="bairro_end" class="input-text required-entry" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    </div>
```

The same part of code in IE7

```
<DIV class=fieldBairro_end></DIV></DIV></LI>
<LI class=fields>
<DIV class=field><LABEL class=required id=complemento_end for=bairro_end><EM>*</EM>Bairro</LABEL> 
<DIV class=input-box><INPUT class="input-text required-entry" id=bairro_end title=bairro_end name=bairro_end> </DIV></DIV>
</LI></UL></DIV>
```

This  is cosing a tag called 
But in IE9 this tag appear in a line very below it

While I'm trying make a JQuery or JavaScript to solve it
Thanks for any help

André

Comment: That's too bad. If you could provide us with a link to your page we could maybe have a look at that for you.

Comment: Is your HTML properly structured? An example?

Answer (score 0):

Using LI tags without UL tags is not a valid markup.
Duplicate question:

[Is using <li> without enclosing <ul> tags dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031725/is-using-li-without-enclosing-ul-tags-dangerous)

You'd better change your layout to use regular DIV tag instead of LI.

Comment: There are a <ul> covering these <li> in my page, but IE put one more <ul> and more DIV's

Comment: You'd better presented YOUR code and NOT code generated by some browser. It seems that YOUR code is bad formatted and that is the reason why it is parsed differently in different browsers.

Comment: This HTML is not generated by no code, it's a pure PHTML view contained in a magento template, i'm checking in w3c validator yet, thanks for help