# HTML5 - Does <li> have to be inside of <ul>?

Tags: html, syntax

I know, that the only childred of the `<ul>` can be `<li>` elements. However, I can not find any requirement, whether the `<li>` can be used without `<ul>` element?

Is the following code correct?

```
<p>some elements, nevermind</p>
<li>Oh! This has a point</li>
<li>another one!</li>
<p>and here the rest of the site goes...</p>
```

I know, that it seems to be pointless, but I write some kind of very basic CMS, in which I need to replace [[li]] marks with elements of a list, so if above is correct, I would not need to make a lot of logic, to add  element before the first [[li]] and < /ul > behind the last one.

So in a word - does HTML5 syntax allow me to use < li > without < ul >?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is using <li> without enclosing <ul> tags dangerous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031725/is-using-li-without-enclosing-ul-tags-dangerous)  'It's not a valid markup at all'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Straight from the [W3 HTML5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) (This is a candidate spec, I'd actually recommend
[kazagistar's W3 link](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html) which includes the `<menu>` element too.):

> 4.5.7 The li element
>
> Categories:
>       None. Contexts in which this element can be used:
>       Inside ol elements.
>       Inside ul elements.
>
> The li element represents a list item. If its parent element is an ol, or ul, then the element is an item of the parent element's list, as defined for those elements. Otherwise, the list item has no defined list-related relationship to any other li element.

The W3 Spec shows that you should only use a list item element when it's inside an ordered or unordered list element or a menu element.

Comment: Oh, I feel dumb... I was searching Google for half an hour and did not notice this... Sorry! I should do more research, and, yeah, rtfm...

Comment: I'd say the doc does NOT say you "should only use" them with a parent. Without the parent, the LI items have no relation, but I don't see the doc saying "thou shalt not".

Comment: I did notice this too. From my perspective it seems to be a bit contradictory. First it states that it should be used inside of `ol`, `li`, or `menu`, but then goes on to say that if it doesn't, well no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

[See the w3 standard pages here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html)

Permitted parent elements: ul, ol, menu

Answer (score -1):

@Paweł Tokarz:
"So in a word - does HTML5 syntax allow me to use < li > without < ul >?"

Answer: yes it does, but with: ol or menu, that's all!

check this:
 "li element can be nested inside the next HTML elements:"
source: 
 http://w3-video.com/Web_Technologies/HTML5/li/html5_li_tag_nested.php

Answer (score -2):

Yes as per html standards we write

inside .. yes you can use without  also.. basically  use to add custom css for every

its like a container..