# Rows within a row in Angular JS table with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table like so. Within each program, I have multiple forms. Each form has a name, a Default YES/NO field (the tick mark if yes) and a status field ACTIVE/INACTIVE.

The problem is however that my current code messes up the alignment. The red lines indicate all the items that should be aligned in a single row.

[image: Screenshot of table]

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="scrollContainer">
<div class="fixedHeaderSection">
    <table class="table columnHeadings" style="table-layout: fixed">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                Program
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                Forms
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                Status
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="scrollableSection">
    <table class="table columnData" style="table-layout: fixed">
        <tr ng-repeat="program in programsList">
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                {{program.name}}
            </td>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <li ng-repeat="form in program.forms" style="list-style:none;">
                    {{form.name}}
                </li>
                + New Form
            </td>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                <li ng-repeat="form in program.forms" style="list-style:none;">
                    <span ng-cloak ng-if="form.default == 'YES'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                </li>
            </td>
            <td style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <li ng-repeat="form in program.forms" style="list-style:none;">
                    {{form.status}}
                </li>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: beware li without ul http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031725/is-using-li-without-enclosing-ul-tags-dangerous

Comment: Can you please provide an example plnkr or jsfiddle. I cant replicate what you are describing.

Comment: Other than the messy `li` without `ul`, I don't see any issues. Are you sure the data is working correctly? Maybe your problem isn't layout, but the data is being passed to the wrong scope object? Put up a jsfiddle with a controller and actual data. Here is a template jsfiddle you can fork, if it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/v015227L/

Comment: @daremachine noted the `li` without the `ul`, thanks.

Comment: The problem is most likely that you want your `li` elements to be aligned in the 'correct' rows. But this is not guaranteed in any way, because long `li` texts will get broken down, and the list in the next column cannot know about this.

Comment: @Rouby exactly! I was wondering how to avoid that. Any other way I can structure my table? jsfiddle coming right up.

Comment: @geekchic You can remove the lis and add a new table inside second td. [Heres a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0tZApa03eIDZMne1EfxT?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you want your li elements to be aligned in the 'correct' rows. But this is not guaranteed in any way, because long li texts will get broken down, and the list in the next column cannot know about this.

You should consider adding further rows to your table for every form in a program and use rowspan or something on the first column.

Its kinda messy but should get it done.

Link to a "working" plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/Q9Ikmo3GVvtm3MdYlPNY?p=preview

```
  <table class="table columnData" style="table-layout: fixed" border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="program in programsList">
      <td style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" rowspan="{{program.forms.length + 1}}">
        {{program.name}}
      </td>
      <td style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        + New Form
      </td>
      <td style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
      </td>
      <td style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="form in program.forms">
      <td>
        {{form.name}}
      </td>
      <td><span ng-cloak ng-if="form.default == 'YES'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></td>
      <td>{{form.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: This would work, but I was hoping there might be a simpler solution I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. I deleted the li and used "rowspan". 
You were using 2 tables, so I correct it whit using only one (thead + tbody)

```
<div class="scrollContainer">
        <table class="table columnHeadings" style="table-layout: fixed">
        <div class="fixedHeaderSection">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                Program
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                Forms
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                Status
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        </div>
        <tbody>
        <div class="scrollableSection">

        <tr ng-repeat="program in programsList">
            <td rowspan="program.forms.length" style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                {{program.name}}
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat="form in program.forms" style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                {{form.name}}
                + New Form
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat="form in program.forms" style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                <span ng-cloak ng-if="form.default == 'YES'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat="form in program.forms" style="word-wrap: break-word;" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                {{form.status}}
            </td>
        </tr>

        </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I think the two tables are intended, fixedHeader and scrollSection give a hint.

Comment: The forms get displayed as columns in your code rather than as rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about restructuring HTML, this might be most simple solution.

```
<tr ng-repeat="program in programsList">
    <td class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        {{program.name}}
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-8">
        <div ng-repeat="form in program.forms">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                {{form.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
                <span ng-cloak ng-if="form.default == 'YES'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                {{form.status}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            + New Form
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This example might need to be adjust a little bit because this is without test.  The point is to use **single loop** for 'program.forms'.