# react render failed using stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to use stateless component with fetch but failed, the fetch api is working, I'm able to get the data but somehow I see nothing appear in my stateless component

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardText } from 'material-ui/Card';
import { map } from 'lodash';

const AdminDashboard = (users) => (
  <Card className="container">
    <CardTitle
      title="Approve applicants"
    />
    {map(users, user =>
        <li key={user._id}>{user.email}</li>
    )}
  </Card>
);

AdminDashboard.propTypes = {
  users: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default AdminDashboard;
```

My container for admin dashboard is here https://pastebin.com/raw/UtxZLh3a

I have no clue why this is not working.

Comment: What does `users` look like?

Comment: Also, you are importing from AdminDashboard.jsx, but the code above is Javascript. Maybe that's confusing Babel?

Comment: any reason of using `lodash map`, why not using directly like this: `users.map()`. Check the `console` also are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `constructor` in `AdminDashboardPage` to be

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    users: [] // <----- array instead of object
  }
}
```

As a side note, [you really should put your `li` tags inside some `ul` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031729/6902543).