# Why my foreach is is not giving me the results i expected?

Tags: php, arrays, database, foreach

```
<?php 

    define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', null);

    define('DB_DATABASE', 'publicacoes');
    define('DB_PREFIX', 'bn');
    define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

?>

<?php

function DBclose($link){
    @mysqli_close($link) or die(mysqli_error($link));
}

function DBConnect(){
    $link = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARSET) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    return $link;
}
?>

<?php

function DBRead($table, $params = null, $fields = '*'){
    $table  = DB_PREFIX.'_'.$table;
    $params = ($params) ? " {$params}" : null;

    $query  = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$params}";
    $result = DBExecute($query);

    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
        return false;
    else{
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[] = $res;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}

function DBExecute($query, $insertId = false){
    $link   = DBConnect();
    $result = @mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    if($insertId)
        $result = mysqli_insert_id($link);


    DBClose($link);
    return $result;
}
?>

<?php

$publicacao = DBRead('publicacao');
    foreach ($publicacao as $pl):
    endforeach;

?>


    <? foreach ($publicacao as $pl): ?>
        <li>
            <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $pl['title']?></a></h4>

            <h5><?php echo $pl['text']?><a href="%">Continue lendo &raquo;</a></h5>
        </li>
    <? endforeach; ?>

    <? foreach ($publicacao as $pl): ?>
        <li>
            <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $pl['title']?></a></h4>

            <h5><?php echo $pl['text']?><a href="%">Continue lendo &raquo;</a></h5>
        </li>
    <? endforeach; ?>
```

I put a `var_dump` in the variable `$publicacao` and it's ok, but my `foreach` is only printing out one record on both `li`. What's wrong?

How can i solve this? I did't found any similar questions on Stackoverflow. And I was not able to find the problem. I'm new about using MYSQLi and 
i'm giving my best, but this problem is giving me a little headache.

Edit:

The results from the `print_r($publicacao)`

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 33 [title] => First Title [text] => First Text ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 34 [title] => Second Title [text] => Second Text ) )

Comment: are you aware you have `foreach ($publicacao_` and `foreach ($publicacao`, where 2 of the foreaches don't have a `_` after `$publicacao`

Comment: at this line `$publicacao_ = DBRead('publicacao');` your variable is `$publicacao_` with `_` but in foreach loop you are missing `_` and you used `$publicacao `.

Comment: @BilalAhmed Yea, sorry, i was making some tests and i forgot, but i'm with the some problem. Just forgive it. So, could you help me?

Comment: then you should `print_r($publicacao_)` and show us result

Comment: @BilalAhmed Please check my Edit, on the question.

Comment: @Sean Read my comment please

Comment: Maybe it's only your browser that doesn't show the other items, because you missed `<ul>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031725/is-using-li-without-enclosing-ul-tags-dangerous

Comment: @Kerkouch Actualy i have a `<ul>` in my script, i just put it out on my question, anyway, on my browser it does not make difference.

Comment: Can you share with us your script, I do not see anything wrong on that part you added to your question.

Comment: @Kerkouch This is my whole script, i just took the important parts from my "main script" and put in this question. I'm sure that the issue can be seem in this script, because i tested it before i made the question. If you have the Apache server, you can just made a file and put this whole script and your htdoc. Could you help me?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `foreach` loops on your script.

Comment: @Kerkouch Yea, as we can see on the `print_r($publicacao)`, but why it's only printing out one record to both `<li>`?

Comment: Something is wrong with the other parts of your code.

Comment: I agree with @Kerkouch, the issue is with code you are not showing. I tested your code, with your sample data, and see no issues - https://3v4l.org/Ehb2a

Comment: @Sean I as i said before, it's my whole code. You are specifying the values on the `array` directly, could you test my code that i put on the question please? You will see the issue.

Comment: Have you looked at the resulting source code to see what is actually there? all it takes is a missing `"`/`'`/`<`/`>`/etc and your browser view will not show everything

Comment: @Sean Yea, and it's all fine, it only print out 1 record on both `<li>`. How could it be possible? I tested it on the Chrome and Mozilla, they are showing the same.

Comment: @Kerkouch Do you have any idea about how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment

At this line `$publicacao_ = DBRead('publicacao');` your variable is `$publicacao_` with `_` but in `foreach loop` you are missing `_` and you used `$publicacao`

```
$publicacao_ = DBRead('publicacao');

<? foreach ($publicacao_ as $pl): ?> //replace $publicacao with $publicacao_
    <li>
        <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $pl['title']?></a></h4>

        <h5><?php echo $pl['text']?><a href="%">Continue lendo &raquo;</a></h5>
    </li>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, just forget this _, i was doing some tests to solve my problem, and i forgot put this _ out. Anyway need to solve my problem yet.