# How to ng-repeat response data

Tags: php, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-http

I have a simple piece of code that sends *data* to php for processing and then it returns it.
I would like to ng-repeat that *data* in the page, I just can't tell what isn't right.
I must point out to the fact that I am but a novice, therefore I might be overlooking something..

So I have this in the controller:

```
  $scope.one = function () {
  $http({
  method: "POST",
  url: 'destination.php',
  data: {'message' : something},
  })
  .then(function(response)
  {
  $scope.message = response.data.results;
  }
  )}
```

This is how the data goes to PHP and back from it:

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$outp = "";
if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
$outp .= '{"REZCMD":"'  . $params["message"] . '"}';
$outp ='{ "results":[ '.$outp.' ] }';
echo $outp;
```

example:

```
{ "results":[ {"REZCMD":"somethingprocessed"} ] }
```

And this is the HTML

```
  <div ng-repeat="x in message track by $index"></div>
   <li>{{message}}
   <li>{{x.REZCMD}}
```

Which prints this:
(example)

```
*[{"REZCMD":"1003372"}]
*
```

EDIT

For this result:

```
{ "results":[ {"REZCMD":"1003372"} ] }
```

What I am expecting should look like this:

1003372

Comment: share your research and expectations on the description.

Comment: you close your div tag of ng-repeat before  {{x. REZCMD}} so x is not accessible, you should write {{x.whatever}} in that repeated div only.

Comment: I have checked that, but it didn't help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you required to print only value then :

```
<div>
   <li ng-repeat="obj in message">{{obj.REZCMD}}</li>
</div>
```

This method is listed in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: What I need is to print the value.
The results match your description, as per the example above

Comment: add your expected result in your description.

Comment: Hello Vinit
Thank you for your answer, it works now, actually I think the problem was that the <li> didn't have the closing tag..
Thanks for leading me to the solution

Comment: I hope you are enclosing in <ul> instead of <div>. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031725/is-using-li-without-enclosing-ul-tags-dangerous

Answer (score 0):

May be, the below code is what you wanted:

```
<ul>
   <li>{{message}}</li>
   <li ng-repeat="x in message track by $index">{{x.REZCMD}}</li>
</ul>
```