# Difference between display items using li vs p tags?

Tags: css

So I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a card that has multiple features, and it works fine with `<p>` tags, but is it okay to create `<li>` tags without a ul? or is that bad practice?

Here's my code for now using `<p>` tags

```
 <div class="membership__card">
      <h3>Membership Red</h3>
      <p>Gym</p>
      <p>Group Fitness Classes</p>
      <p>Private Personal Training</p>
      <p>Tanning Bed</p>
      <p>$199 per month</p>
    </div>
```

But am I able to write it like this or do I need to replace the p tags with li's?

```
 <div class="membership__card">
      <h3>Membership Red</h3>
      <li>Gym</li>
      <li>Group Fitness Classes</li>
      <li>Private Personal Training</li>
      <li>Tanning Bed</p>
      <li>$199 per month</li>
    </div>
```

But wouldn't I need to wrap these with a UL? also am I allowed to pass a non `li` tag inside of the ul like my h3 tag?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li Look in the blue box below the examples. There's a line labeled **Permitted parents** that notes that the only permitted parents of `li` are `ul`, `ol`, and `menu`.  Click on `ul` and there's a similar box, with a line "Permitted content" which notes that only `li`, `template`, and `script` elements are allowed.

Comment: Keep your <p>s . CSS has nothing to do with semantics and you can use any kind of display rules for any tags, this the purpose of CSS, styling. so `p{display:list-item}`won't hurt ;). You can also wrap <li>s inside an `<ol>` or an `<ul>`

Comment: ah okay just wanted to double check. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `li` without `ul` as a parent is **bad practice**.

Most browsers will not render any default styling to the `li` without `ul`. Any styling applied to it via inline, or CSS selector might not take either. Most modern browsers I have used wouldn't care and would treat it as a normal element; however, this isn't consistent across all browsers. In place of `li`, I would recommend using `p`, `span`, or `div` elements instead. **I would not recommend** using `li` without an enclosed `ul` parent element as each browser will handle it differently.

Someone already asked a similar question to this here on stackoverflow: [Is using <li> without enclosing <ul> tags dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031725/is-using-li-without-enclosing-ul-tags-dangerous)

Heretic Monkey linked the Mozilla documentation on this as a comment and it's also worth a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

If you want time to read the official documentation (it's long) on the `li` tag, here it is straight from W3C: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-li-element