# How to edit childrens div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code (and the number of components that I want to edit it's variable, it could be 3 or 20).

I have created a small example with similar scenario on my website

As you can see my script is able to edit the father div and add the classname. Same for firstchild.

I would like to edit all divs inside firstchild but not the immediately div, it has to be two inside.

Any ideas why my code is not working on the last part?
Thanks.

```js
// WORKS OK
var firstc = document.getElementById('father');

firstc.classList.add("father-class");
firstc.children[0].children[0].children[0].setAttribute("id", "firstchild"); // WORKS OK

var second = document.getElementById('firstchild');
second.classList.add("child-class");


// NOT WORKING
var grandchildren = second.children[0].children[0].children[0];
for (let z = 0; z < grandchildren.length; z++) {
  grandchildren[z].classList.add("slide");
}
```

```html
<div id="father">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="firstchild">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="random63637236">
              <li>1</li>
            </div>
            <div class="generic">
              <li>2</li>
            </div>
            <div class="italy_gdgd">
              <li>3</li>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't you need some ULs? The LIs on their own are [not valid HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031725/is-using-li-without-enclosing-ul-tags-dangerous)

Comment: Hey, the LI it's added just to be able to right click inspect and see classes names.

Comment: @Hahshw well, don't. LI is not a valid descendant of `<div>` and you're left purely  on browser interpretation which could always result in unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code is the last `children[0]`. you are selecting only the first div, it's not an array. Fix that line and everything will work

```js
var grandchildren = second.children[0].children[0].children;
```

As a side note: if for some reason the first or the second `.children[0]` are undefined you will get an error.
A better approach is to use `querySelectorAll` which returns an array;
if your array it is empty, nothing happens.

```js
second.querySelectorAll('#firstchild > div > div > div')
  .forEach(el => el.classList.add('slide'))
```