# Scroll bug (lagging)

Tags: html, css, sass, scroll

I have a problem with scrolling elements in html. There's no much space for blocks and I decided to make a scrolling block instead of using burger menu and etc. When I try to scroll it stucks, lags and do some strange moves. I've already used "margin/padding/display/position" ways to solve the problem, it didn't help, I don't know why does this problem exist.

Here some code of my scrollbar

```
.checklist-nav
  overflow-x: scroll 
  display: -webkit-box
  padding-bottom: 12px
  margin-left: 5px
  &::-webkit-scrollbar
    height: 7px
    border: 1px solid #ffffff27
    border-radius: 50px
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
    background: #ffffff2a
    border-radius: 50px
```

[That's the gif of scroll problem (imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy2RN.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok for me. Can you send the HTML and CSS code of the options?

### EDIT:

I think the problem is `</li>` without enclosing `</ul>` tag, [look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2031771/13190410)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #4B80A7;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 100vh;
}

#main {
  height: 50%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: -webkit-box;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff27;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ffffff2a;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
}

.op {
  height: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 40px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap" id="wrap">

  <div id="main">
    <div class="op"></div>
    <div class="op"></div>
    <div class="op"></div>
    <div class="op"></div>
    <div class="op"></div>
    <div class="op"></div>
    <div class="op"></div>
    <div class="op"></div>
    <div class="op"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: it's html https://i.imgur.com/IunwPsC.jpg ,
css https://i.imgur.com/yvXlO0N.jpeg

Comment: I think the problem is </li> without enclosing </ul> tag, look https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031771/13190410

Comment: Can you send the CSS code of the items inside the nav?